# Variable isn't being defined

Tags: ruby, variables

I'm just playing around with stuff trying to understand it, it is saying

```
:/Ruby Tutorials/dragonhealth.rb:9:in `<main>': undefined local variable or met
od `toughness' for main:Object (NameError)
```

and I can't figure out for the life of me why the variable isn't being defined.  It accepts the inputs from the gets.chomp.to_i just fine this line, which seems super simple, is breaking it

```
health + armor = toughness


def dragon_toughness(health, armor)
puts "The dragon's health is #{health}!"
puts "The dragon's armor is #{armor}!"
end
puts "What is the dragon's health?"
health = gets.chomp.to_i
puts "What is the dragon's armor?"
armor = gets.chomp.to_i

health + armor = toughness

dragon_toughness(health, armor)

if toughness > 40
puts "Wow, tough dragon!"
elsif
    toughness <= 40
puts "That dragon is kinda weak son!"

end
```

Comment: it seems to have pushed that method together during copy and paste, with the stuff below it... sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the line

```
  health + armor = toughness
```

as

```
  toughness = health + armor
```

Full code (pasted in my file `so.rb`) :

```
def dragon_toughness(health, armor)
  puts "The dragon's health is #{health}!"
  puts "The dragon's armor is #{armor}!"
end

puts "What is the dragon's health?"
health = gets.chomp.to_i
puts "What is the dragon's armor?"
armor = gets.chomp.to_i

toughness = health + armor

dragon_toughness(health, armor)

if toughness > 40
  puts "Wow, tough dragon!"
elsif
  toughness <= 40
  puts "That dragon is kinda weak son!"  
end
```

Let's run it :

```
(arup~>Ruby)$ ruby so.rb
What is the dragon's health?
12
What is the dragon's armor?
13
The dragon's health is 12!
The dragon's armor is 13!
That dragon is kinda weak son!
(arup~>Ruby)$
```